# What's the proper way to go about replacing this faucet fixture? Is it always replace every part at once or can I mix and match if I like part of it?

Tags: faucet, plumbing-fixture, kitchen-sink

[image]

So I really like the handles of this sink fixture but I want to change the spigot to something that has a sprayer you can pull out to rinse the hard to reach corners of the sink.

The part where the red arrow is unscrews and comes out. Do hardware stores like home depot sell just this part of the fixture or do I have to replace the entire thing? If I have to replace the entire thing I assume it means I have to find one that will fit the same footprint of this one? Are these generally a standard width apart?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Pull-Outs work very differently and can't just screw-on to the old faucet...anywhere in your case. Their sprayer's quite long hose must nest down into the sink cabinet or the wall's void.

Although, if you can remove the handle caps and unscrew the handles to take them to the store, then you may find a new faucet setup that lets you use the old handles on the new faucet.

Lastly, you may also keep the perfectly fine faucet and plumb-in a separate sprayer installed in the wall next to your faucet or on the countertop. This is a bit involved and a sprayer and hose intended/rated for constant pressure is needed...like a Pot-Filler's separate setup.

A Plumber would be best to use for that last bit and they can renew washers and whatnot in the old faucet to ensure a decade or more of continued admiration.

Comment: Could I DIY an install of something like this: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Tosca-2-Handle-Wall-Mount-Pull-Down-Sprayer-Kitchen-Faucet-in-Chrome-255-K820-T/300954687? Is it as simple as shutting off the water taking the old faucet out and putting the new one in? Any gotchas to be wary of as someone who has never done this before?

Comment: It might, if you want a Pull-Down rather than a Pull-out. But, personally, I wouldn't give up the very much better Ceramic Disc valves. Otherwise, yeah it should be a rather simple straight replacement...assuming the spread dimensions are the same and the piping is actually screwed to the structure, to handle the Pull-Down load.

Comment: Ok you've lost me. What are ceramic disc valves? They only come in pull out faucets not pull down? And what if the piping is not screwed to the structure? What else could it be?

Comment: Ceramic Disc valves, means there aren't any short-lived rubber washers. They call them Ceramic Cartridges in the HD description. The piping should be solid, but it's possible they're loose and the fittings are just sandwiching the backsplash. That's fine for the current faucet, but it may be a problem for the pull-down.

Comment: As far as I can see looking behind and under the sink the hoses connecting to the faucet fixture just dangle down and then connect to the plumbing. Is that okay for this faucet? https://www.homedepot.com/p/Kingston-Brass-Modern-2-Handle-Wall-Mount-Pull-Down-Sprayer-Kitchen-Faucet-in-Satin-Nickel-HGS8288DL/304968211

Comment: Nope. The new faucet is meant to be attached directly to the plumbing (hard-piped) and doesn't use hoses at all. You'll need to find out exactly what the old faucet situation is and remove it to see what will work for a straight replacement. Or, of course, get a plumber to properly install the new faucet you're currently eyeing.

Comment: So it looks like this underneath https://imgur.com/a/YYQycRY. I do not understand why I won't be able to connect the new faucet to where the old one was.

Comment: Yep, it looks like you might luck out with the new faucet going in...assuming the top elbows are the correct size. I thought you meant hoses were going down behind the wall to the valves. It looks like they got real lazy and did a rather ridiculous hose setup. But, it works and hoses will need to be replaced now or in the future. Give it a whirl, I'll keep my fingers crossed.

Answer (score 0):

In general you cannot find variant parts that fit a given fixture. So you cannot find a part that will screw into the existing fixture but with a sprayer, unless the manufacturer of your existing one has a model with that feature.

The distance between the supply lines is usually a standard value such as 4 inches (10 cm), 6 inches (15 cm), 8 inches (20 cm).